# How to change the font of various terminal emulators?

Tags: command-line, fonts, customization

Mainly:

- Gnome Terminal
- Xfce Terminal
- Konsole
- LXTerminal
- Terminator
- Guake
- Yakuake
- Urxvt
- Xterm
- Mrxvt

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Gnome Terminal:**

- Open Gnome Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
- Go to: `Edit` ➤ `Profile Preferences`.
- In the profile window under General tab uncheck ☐ `Use the system fixed width font`.
- Click on font selection button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
  [image: Gnome Terminal]

**Xfce Terminal Emulator:**

- Open Xfce Terminal: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `xfce4-terminal` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Go to: `Edit` ➤ `Preferences`
- In preferences window under `Appearance` tab click on font selection button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
  [image: Xfce Terminal Emulator]

**Konsole:**

- Open Konsole: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `konsole` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Go to: `Settings` ➤ `Configure Konsole` ➤ `Profiles`.
- If the current profile is read-only, click `Create Profile`.
- Click `Edit`.
- In the `Appearance` ➤ `Colour Scheme & font` tab click on `Choose` button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
- Close and reopen Konsole.
  [image: Konsole]

**LXTerminal:**

- Open LXTerminal: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lxterminal` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Go to: `Edit` ➤ `Preferences`.
- In the resulting window under `Style` tab click on font selection button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
  [image: LXTerminal]

**Terminator:**

- Open Terminator: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `terminator` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Right click on terminal window, in the resulting menu click on `Preferences`.
- In Preferences window go to `Profiles` tab, under `General` tab uncheck ☐ `Use the system fixed width font`.
- Click on font selection button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
  [image: Terminator]

**Guake:**

- Open Guake preferences: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `guake-prefs` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In preferences window under `Appearance` tab uncheck ☐ `Use the system fixed width font`.
- Click on Font selection button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
  [image]

**Yakuake:**

- Open Yakuake: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `yakuake` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> or whatever key you've set to bring Yakuake forward.
- Right click on terminal window, in the resulting menu click on `Edit Current Profile...`.
- In the profile window under `Appearance` tab click on `Select Font` button and choose your desired font from resulting dialog.
  [image]

Terminals listed below doesn't provide GUI to change font. You can use `Font Viewer` to view and choose the font. Top open `Font Viewer` go to Unity dash by hitting <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for `font viewer`.

**Urxvt/Xterm:**

- Open `~/.Xresources` in your favorite editor:

  ```
    gedit ~/.Xresources
  ```

For `Urxvt` add:

```
    URxvt*.font: xft:Source\ Code\ Pro:Regular:size=10
```

For `Xterm` add:

```
    Xterm*.font: xft:Source\ Code\ Pro:Regular:size=10
```

Change `Source\ Code\ Pro` with the font you want to apply. Change `Regular` with font style you want to use, like: Bold, Italic, Bold\ Italic. Set the `size` to your desired font size.

**Mrxvt:**

- Open the `~/.mrxvt` file in your favorite editor:

  ```
    gedit ~/.mrxvt
  ```

and add following lines to it:

```
    Mrxvt.xft:              1
    Mrxvt.xftFont:          Source\ Code\ Pro
    Mrxvt.xftSize:          13
    Mrxvt.xftAntialias:     1
```

Comment: I've covered only some popular terminals hare, feel free to add your answers about other terminals.

Comment: Basharat, for changes to .Xresources e.g.Urxvt it would be worthwhile to run xrdb -merge .Xresources afterwards, for the edits to take effect without rebooting the system, or even restarting X

Comment: You misspelled `XTerm`.

Comment: How do I change the font for eg. xfce4-terminal without using the GUI/mouse. So just via command line?

Comment: In Terminator, note that the font setting under "Global" only affects the title bar. The actual CLI font is under the Profile, even though you would imagine global would change every place in Terminator.